# Repeated measures techniques for uneven trials per condition?

Tags: regression, anova, repeated-measures

if I have a data set with 3 within-subjects conditions, with different number of trials on each (e.g., cond. A = 8 trials, cond. B = 6 trials, cond. C = 5 trials), what repeated measures technique can I use to evaluate for a within-subjects effect? Is using repeated measures ANOVA fine? I tried using a repeated measures logistic regression via GEE but it says something about "Hessian matrix is singular". Any thoughts on techniques for analyzing uneven number of trials per condition?

Answer (score 2):

In a repeated-measures ANOVA you can only have one observation per cell of the design and unit of observation. Hence, you would need to aggregate the individual trials per unit of observation and within-subject condition in each case. The issue of differences in numbers of trials would automatically disappear.

An alternative would be to calculate a mixed model with fixed-effects for the within-subjects condition and random-intercepts for subject as well as by-subject random-slopes for the within-subject condition. In this case you would not need to aggregate the data within each cell. The mixed model automatically deals with the different numbers of trials per condition (the consequence being that the precision of the condition means decreases form A to C).

Without more information about the design and example data hardly anything more can be said.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response. Can you please confirm whether or not the repeated measures binary logistic regression via the GEE procedure also would account for differences in number of trials (like the Mixed models can do)?

Comment: @Estuche I have never used GEEs, so I cannot confirm anything about them. But it seems in general unlikely that different numbers of trials across conditions for procedures that allow for different numbers would have any negative effect. I have no intuition on how and why it should come to such an outcome.